# Error passing map to a function in imported Golang package

Tags: go, namespaces

I need to send a map to a function declared in a imported package, and keep getting this error:

> ./main.go:21: cannot use m (type map[string]ticket) as type map[string]some_package.ticket in function argument

This is the code of main.go in golang GOPATH folder:

```
package main

import (    
        "time"
         sp "./some_package"
        )

type ticket struct {
  Timestamp int64
  Identification_number int
}
var m map[string]ticket


func main() {
  humans := 10
  m = make(map[string]ticket)
  m["ticket1"] = ticket{time.Now().Unix(), 1234}
  sp_ := sp.New(humans)
  sp_.SetTicket(m)
}
```

And this is the code of some_package.go in /some_package in golang GOPATH folder:

```
package some_package

type park struct{
  card map[string]ticket
  people int
}

type ticket struct {
  Timestamp int64
  Identification_number int
}

func (p *park) SetTicket(m map[string]ticket)(){

}

func New(humans int)(p *park){
  p.card = make(map[string]ticket)
  p.people = humans
  return p
}
```

How should I pass the value of the map to the imported package function or get the map value inside the function
from the parent package?
Is this even possible or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the two types are named the same and contain the same structure, they are not the same type. A type always belongs to a package, and those two types belong to different packages.

So you shouldn't copypaste the type `ticket` from `some_package` to `main`, but instead 1. export it to other packages by naming it in uppercase: `type Ticket struct`; and 2. use it from `main` like `make(map[string]sp.Ticket)`.

Comment: By the way, `"./some_package"` as a path to a package is valid, but not recommended. See the [how to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) tutorial.